# C# tcpclient how to start tcp/ip keepalive function

Tags: c#, tcpclient

When I set

```
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, inOptionValues, null);
```

Ok I find it works! Bug when I use wireshark to observe the data, I find the package length is 1 and the value is 00.
When I see the protocol of keepalive the length will be 0. This problem puzzled me for a long time. Can anyone can give me a hand?
[Wirehark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nP3v.png)

Comment: Why should the packet length be 0? Reading up a little on keepalive shows me the server sends a packet with the ACK flag set and nothing else, so the length being 1 looks good

Comment: Keepalive functionality is not very useful on transport layer. What if the remote process is deadlocked or in some other zombie state? You will have the impression that everything is okay, but it is not. You have to introduce ping in your own communication protocol, and only then you will know that other side is ready for your messages.

Comment: i review  the contents in RFC 1122 about keepalive mechanism.it says :" if a keep-alive mechanism is implemented,An implementation SHOULD send a keep-alive segment with no data; however, it MAY be configurable to send a keep-alive segment containing one garbage octet, for compatibility with erroneous TCP implementations" ,is that means we can configure  the segment? the question is how to configure the segment with C# tcpclient？